# Forward and pass data along in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post

In Asp.net Entity Framework I need to forward to another page and pass some data processed by the second page along.

In PHP I could do something like

```
<!-- page1.php -->
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go to page 2" />
</form>


<!-- page2.php -->
<?php
    echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

How can this be implemented in Asp.net?

**Edit**: There is a simple solution using Javascript and jQuery.

```
<!-- on page 1 -->
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
    // Forward to browsing page and pass id in URL
    e.preventDefault();
    var id= $('input[name=id]').val();
    if ("" == id)
        return;

    window.location.href = "@Request.Url.OriginalString/page2?id=" + id;
});

<!-- on page 2 -->
alert("@Request.QueryString["id"]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, at least, two options:

1. Session state, like this:

   Putting data into `Session` (your first page)

   ```
   Session["Id"] = HiddenFieldId.Value;
   ```

   Getting data out of `Session` (your second page)

   ```
   // First check to see if value is still in session cache
   if(Session["Id"] != null)
   {
       int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"]);
   }
   ```
2. Query string, like this:

   Putting the value into the URL for the second page as a query string

   ```
   http://YOUR_APP/Page2.aspx?id=7
   ```

   Reading the query string in the second page

   ```
   int id = Request.QueryString["id"]; // value will be 7 in this example
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to do this, take a look at [`this link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some guidance.

HTML page:

```
 <form method="post" action="Page2.aspx" id="form1" name="form1">
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value='test' />
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
 </form>
```

Code in Page2.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = Request["id"];
    }
```

**MVC** would look like...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("page2", "controllername", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden(f => f.id)
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
}
```

also, read through these [`MVC tutorials`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials), you shouldn't blindly translate what you know in PHP to ASP.NET MVC, since you need to learn the MVC pattern too.

Comment: In my project, page2 is a cshtml file. I cannot out a C# method in it, can I?

Comment: Thank you for the sample code how to send data in an MVC application. And how can I get the posted id now from page2?

Comment: What does your controller look like currently? update the question with what you've got.

Comment: Came to a simpler solution using Javascript and jQuery. Thank you for your efforts anyway!

Comment: OK, as I said earlier, you should go through the MVC tutorial as this might be a very limited solution.  What if you wanted to post a full object to the other view with multiple properties etc.  It's worth reading how model binding works in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<form>` with `method="POST"` in ASP.NET. And get value in code:

```
int id = int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]);
```